# Weblogic 10.0: advantages with database connectivity and gotchas?

Tags: database, jdbc, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

What advantages (if any) does Weblogic 10.0 provide in terms of database connectivity (to any database) over open source or commercial alternatives?

Are there any Weblogic specific gotchas with using a Weblogic database connection?

I'm a Java EE, Weblogic newbie so please excuse the simple questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What advantages (if any) does Weblogic 10.0 provide in terms of database connectivity (to any database) over open source or commercial alternatives?

Weblogic supports *clustering of JDBC objects* (data sources, connection pools and multipools) and *failover and load balancing of JDBC connections* and the administration part is very mature. Having that said, I'm sure some other products (some of them, not all) do have equivalent features and wonder if the support of such things can thus be considered as an advantage. All I know is that Weblogic support for these features is really good. Actually,  Weblogic is well know for being a rock solid application server and is frequently used for "mission critical" applications. But most applications do not have such needs.

> Are there any Weblogic specific gotchas with using a Weblogic database connection?

I'm not sure what you mean by a "weblogic database connection" but AFAIK **no**.

Answer (score 0):

Connectivity to any database is accomplished through JDBC drivers; it has nothing to do with WebLogic.  If I recall correctly, WebLogic ships with drivers for Oracle, Sybase, and perhaps SQL Server, but you have to add any others that you need.

This is true of all Java EE app servers, commercial or open source.

The value that WebLogic adds is JNDI services and connection pooling.  It allows to configure pools so that connections are checked before users are allowed to use them, stale connections are recycled, etc.  These are features that would be laborious to code on your own.  WebLogic makes it easy to do via configuration.

Comment: Isn't connection pooling provided by most JEE servers?  Is that a WebLogic only feature?

Comment: Yes, of course they do.  Not all of them are as easy to administer as WebLogic is.  I don't know if they all support features for checking connections for freshness as they go in and out.

Answer (score 0):

As of today transparent datasource failover is still a rare feature in opensource servers. Especially the ability to switch in the middle of a connection being used is something you don't see often.

Jboss does allow to enter a second URL for a datasource, but it's a bit of a crude mechanism (the documentation mentions this) and it hasn't been much improved over the years.